# failure to unmount /oldroot on shutdown; is this a problem?

Tags: systemd, linux-mint, nvidia, shutdown, unmounting

At shutdown, Linux Mint 21.1 briefly flashes a warning that systemd couldn’t unmount `/oldroot` or `/oldroot/sys` because the device is busy. It still shuts down and I haven’t noticed anything else amiss. Other people have had this problem, suggesting anything from systemd to nvidia drivers to the kernel itself as the cause. What I want to know is whether this an actual problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: This could be fixed but it's only a problem if this FS cannot be remounted RO, thus you're looking at a possible data loss due to a FS corruption.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It boots back up just fine. The thing is, I’ve seen cases of this related to actual major problems. Is there a general fix for it?

Comment: There's no "general" fix for that.

Comment: Apparently NVIDIA drivers can cause this. Possible solution from Arch forums: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2049247#p2049247