# Linux does not shutdown completely (Failed to unmount /oldroot)

Tags: arch-linux, shutdown, unmounting

I've been having this problem for a few months where Linux just fails to shutdown.

It freezes on the screen where all logs are displayed and stuff, the last line is always:
"kvm: exiting hardware virtualization"

Somewhere in the middle there is either:
"Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy"
or something along the lines of:
"Remounting "/" ext4 with ....." (I am unable to remember the rest)

This does not seem to be distribution specific, but its happening on arch based distributions (I have not tried ubuntu or any other distributions)
It also appears to affect only this laptop, as all other systems running Linux in my house work perfectly.

I also see fit to mention that I am a beginner, but I decided that arch was the best way to learn due to its steep learning curve.

Would be happy to provide any logs needed,
Image provided of the shutdown screen.

Thanks[image: Shutdown screen]

Comment: Weirdly someone using Mint has reported the same issue just recently: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/739339/failure-to-unmount-oldroot-on-shutdown-is-this-a-problem#comment1403877_739339

Comment: Apparently related to NVIDIA drivers. Possible solution from Arch forums: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2049247#p2049247

Comment: Not "apparently": a person with Intel graphics claims they are affected as well. NVIDIA last updated their drivers over two weeks ago - reports have started to appear in the past 24 hours. Kinda not the same timeline at all.

Comment: actually, this issue has been persistent with me for several months, i just never had a reason or the motivation to fix it, since this laptop is for my leisure, and i dont have any important files in it, i just never bothered.
I always just held the power button to just power it off, but it has been happening for several months across various arch-based distributions (dunno about other types of distros)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar a few months ago, also on Arch. The problem was with nvidia modules so if nvidia is present on your system this may help. A couple of modules needed to be unloaded in the shutdown process so I achieved that by adding and enabling the following unit file. Note that I am using the sddm display manager with LXQt. If you are using a different display manager then edit accordingly.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/nvidia-unload-shutdown.service

[Unit]
Description=Remove nvidia modules before shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
After=sddm.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/modprobe -r nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```